# C# asp.net calendar control move the display from the top

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, calendar

Hi in my code whenever I click on a date in the calendar the date shows up at the very top of the screen, but i would like it to be displayed below the calendar instead. Can someone provide the fix please?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div id="text">
    <span>Looking to book an appointment with us? Choose your date below:</span>
    <asp:Calendar ID="myCalendar" runat="server"  OnSelectionChanged="myCalendar_SelectionChanged">
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
        <TitleStyle Font-Bold="true" BorderStyle="Groove" />
        <DayStyle ForeColor="Silver" Font-Bold="true" />                        
    </asp:Calendar>
```

code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Calender : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void myCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("You selected: " + myCalendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString() + " Book it?");

    if (myCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() == "12/25/2015")
        Response.Write(" <b>Christmas CLOSED!</b>");
    if (myCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() == "1/01/2015")
        Response.Write(" <b>Happy New Years CLOSED!</b>");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using Response.Write which outputs text to the beginning of your page.

Use a label to display your messages instead...

**Page**

```
<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="myCalendar" OnSelectionChanged="myCalendar_SelectionChanged" />
<p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCalendarInfo" /></p>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void myCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblCalendarInfo.Text = string.Format("You selected: {0}. Book it?", myCalendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString());

    if (myCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() == "12/25/2015")
        lblCalendarInfo.Text = "<b>Christmas CLOSED!</b>";
    if (myCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() == "1/01/2015")
        lblCalendarInfo.Text = "<b>Happy New Years CLOSED!</b>";
}
```

Comment: Scotty, Thanks a ton!